# What's the music used in the Summer Surprise trailer?

Tags: shantae-half-genie-hero

The music in the [Summer Surprise trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYhNzTfP0Og) seems to be unique to it, not featured in [the Official Soundtrack](https://virt.bandcamp.com/album/shantae-half-genie-hero-ost) itself, at least from what I can hear.

Or am I wrong?

Comment: Whatever it's from, it wasn't (additionally) released as an album... Shazam can't make heads or tails of it :)

Comment: @MiG - And Shazam works on the OST though?

Comment: Let me rephrase: Shazam recognises music released as separate records. It comes up with wildly differing music while attempting to identify this one, so I suspect that the music you're asking about has not been released as an OST. This is definitely possible, teasers and trailers tend to be made by different people and may use different music.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, you are wrong indeed: both tracks aren't unique at all.

The second one that plays when they announce the Sophia III transformation is - quite expectedly - taken straight from Blaster Master Zero, the game Sophia comes from in the first place.

> [Blaster Master Zero OST - Forest Area 1 - The Underground Adventure Begins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZ8WBzTpsBg)

The other one is actually a track used in the game. It is called "Remains" and plays inside the Tassel Town tower ... if you return there after the chase scene you get the first time, which obviously uses a different song. Coincidentally... they even show you that very area when the trailer starts. You can see that being played in the game [here](https://youtu.be/yGYjW0fQ2KI?t=275).

[image]

As for WHY you didn't found that music in the OST... you probably checked the wrong OST. You see, some tracks were only included in the Backer Exclusive OST you got with the "soundtrack tier" backing option for the game [Kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1236620800/shantae-half-genie-hero),

> DIGITAL SOUNDTRACK! Ah yes, the OST! This epic soundtrack will include all the game's tunes, plus ***Kickstarter exclusive Bonus Tracks you won't find anywhere else***.

... at least until it was uploaded to Youtube (and anyway, it is used in the game).

> [Shantae: Half-Genie Hero OST: Bonus Song 1- Remains](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1NamfzjpY9A)